# Text to Speech (Speech Lib) won't speak on IIS7

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

Platform: Windows vista Home premuime

.Net version : 3.5

Does anybody know why TTS won't speak under IIS? I wrote very simple code that speak the input text when i hit submit button. Now the page works fine when i run from File System. As soon as i store on localhost ( IIS) than the code executed succefully but i am not getting any voice but it should work on File System.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking the reason the client's computer won't speak or the reason the server is speaking instead of the client?

Comment: Are you expecting the text-to-speed to play in the browser?  On the server?

Comment: @George - He wants it to play throught he client's browser.  The obvious problem the sound is actually being played on the server.  Of course I am not exactly sure what he means by "File System" :$

Comment: Yes guys i need to play the value of text as a speech to the end user. So i am just trying now from localhost. Its not working. But as i store all project on file system instead in IIS(Default Website) It works like great. But in case of IIS it didn't play the sound but code executed successfully without error. Any idea?

Comment: Ok so let me expand more in depth. I want to play sound in the browser using sound (speechLib.dll) there store on server.File system means when you store all project on your computer in any folder rather than once in intepub/wwwroort directory.i am storing in this wwwroot folder which directly point to IIS.

Comment: Did you understand george and ramhound?

Comment: I would recommend as step one is to figure out how the sound is being sent to the client.  Most likely it is an audio file being created on the fly and downloaded. Use a took like fiddler or firebug to identify the file, and then compare the behavior between the local execution and through iis.  After that you should be able to ask a more clear question without involving text to speech

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your scenario correctly, text on the server needs to be synthesized and played on the client machine.

I believe that SpeechLib is not marked as safe for scripting, so your best option is to **generate a WAV file (using SpeechLib) on the server**, place it into a temporary location and then return some **HTML that references that WAV file on the server**. The browser will then download the WAV file and play it using whatever method you choose (e.g.,  in HTML5, external audio player, etc.).

Let me know if you cannot find an example on how to generate a WAV file using SpeechLib on the server (I was the development lead for System.Speech in a former life).

Comment: Hi Philipp thank you so much... If you give me the complete example for how to generate the wav file from value that i passed into textbox and playback those wav file to the end user in form of HTML5 or SWF..So the main important thing for me was i want to do something like this... If user enter name then some other info for example price , location than i need to convert everything in a speech into only one wav file than play as HTML5 to the end user.